# finding a parametrized curve

Tags: calculus

Let a disc of radius $1$ , and let us make it roll on the x axis.

Now, let us consider a second disc "glued" onto the first one, with the same center.

I want to describe the trajectory of a point located on the edge of the disc using a parametrized curve $c: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$.

I am having trouble doing that, I think I know what the curve looks like but I can't seem to be able to parametrize it.

Answer (score 0):

lets say the big circle has radius $R$ and rotates with a period of $2\pi.$
The small cirlce has radius $r.$
Let make it roll from left to right.
Start with the center at $(0,0).$
The big circle is rolling above the line $L:(0,-R) + (1,0) s$
The circles are making clockwise rotations.

Motion the center of the curve.  And lest make it roll from left to right.

$(R t, 0)$

Motion of the of a point small circle around its center.

$(r\cos-t, r\sin -t)$  minus $t$ because we are rotating in the clockwise direction.

add the two components of motion together.

$(Rt + r\cos -t, r\sin-t)$